# How to scrape data from justdial.com?

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to fetch all the phone numbers and the names of the doctors from the mentioned website. I'm currently facing some issues about scraping the data. I've downloaded the html page for scraping but showing me errors The error is

> Warning:
> file_get_contents(file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/xampp/htdocs/scrape_demo/Top%20Ayurvedic%20Doctors%20in%20kolkata.html):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\xampp\htdocs\scrape_demo\simple_html_dom.php on line 75
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
> C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\scrape_demo\scrape_justdial.php on
> line 4

And here is my code -

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/xampp/htdocs/scrape_demo/Top%20Ayurvedic%20Doctors%20in%20kolkata.html');
    foreach($html->find('div.col-sm-5 col-xs-8 store-details sp-detail paddingR0') as $element){
    echo $element->innertext . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

I'm waiting for the solution

Comment: I'd start by making sure you are passing the correct file location to your class. Also don't use spaces in filenames and work with  `__DIR__`: `$file = __DIR__ . '/Top_Ayurvedic_Doctors_in_kolkata.html';`

Comment: (file_get_content)[http://php.net/file_get_content] does not know about the file protocol. Just use it with a proper path like `C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/xampp/htdocs/scrap_demo/Top%20Ayurvedic%20Doctors%20in%20kolkata.html`

Comment: Thanks. The problem solved now

Comment: @NicoHaase post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[file_get_content](http://php.net/file_get_content) does not know about the file protocol. Just use it with a proper path like `C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/xampp/htdocs/scrape_demo/Top%20Ayu‌​rvedic%20Doctors%20i‌​n%20kolkata.html`